# Where to add an Array?

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance

I have this simple project due tomorrow and I'm almost done but the thing is that one of the requirements in class is for it to have an array, a scanner (which I have) and inheritance.

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class TestScores 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Enter scores from a range of 0 to 100.");
        System.out.println("");
        Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in); 

        int testscore = kbReader.nextInt();
        char grade;

        if (testscore >= 90) {
            grade = 'A';
        } else if (testscore >= 80) {
            grade = 'B';
        } else if (testscore >= 70) {
            grade = 'C';
        } else if (testscore >= 60) {
            grade = 'D';
        } else {
            grade = 'F';
        }
        System.out.println("Grade = " + grade);             
    }    
}
```

I don't know how to incorporate the array and the inheritance.

What would be the subclass?

Comment: you could store the test scores/trigger levels in the array, so instead of a if/else/else chain, you just have a loop. as for inheritance, do something dinky/stupid. define a base class that does your input, then extend that with your grades processing.

Comment: Surely your assignment included some information on what you are supposed to model with the classes and inheritance and what should be stored in the array?

Comment: Can you clarify the inheritance requirement?  What did the teacher tell you to use inheritance for?

Comment: your teacher must be Chuck Norris :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could create a Grade Object lets say so you could now have an array of Grade Objects defined as:

`Grade[10] grades = new Grade[10];` // 10 Grade Objects can be stored

Then i guess based on your code you could have subclasses of Grade so AGrade, BGrade etc.. and have them contain extra information.

```
Class Grade {

     int mark;

     public Grade(int mark){

        this.mark = mark;

     }

}


Class AGrade extends Grade {

       String message = "wooo i got an A";

       public AGrade(){

            //access mark or message or what ever you want to add here
           }    
      }
```

I'll leave the rest of the implementation up to you, but you will need to use super access if you want to access the mark in AGrade. It is not clear how much inheritance you have done but if you come from c++ Java does NOT support multiple inheritance.

I might be wrong in what ive said, but it is hard to tell exactly what you are looking for based on the above, i don't see a real need for subclasses here if you are only using a mark and printing out a char.

The example i give uses a message in each Class, so you can show the difference clearly between subclasses.

Comment: This is just an outline to give OP a general idea to a possible solution. It is not even clear without seeing the specification if this is what they are even looking for.